# Qt gain administrator permissions on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, registry

I need in my Qt c++ program to work on HKLM registry key in some part of my programm. I heard, to do this, I need to gain admin permissions. So, how can I ask for UAC dialog when application is already running? I don't want to ask permissions when initiallising app. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure its possible to elevate permissions after the process has started. I think a workaround is to launch a separate process - create a separate exe with the full permissions - I think the UAC dialog will get popped when you start that process. Another workaround - create a windows service that has full permissions and communicate with that.

Comment: It's not clear at all from the question what you're trying to do, but if you need write access to HKLM you need to launch a second helper app that runs elevated.

Comment: Thank you for informations :)